# Apply actions on Javascript events depending on current view context in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS SPA which has multiple elements that I want to bind keypress events to. The difficulty comes in the fact that, due to the Pinterest style modal window routing, several of the elements, and thus controller scopes, can be visible at once. This means that certain keypress event will fire in more than one controller, including potential background content.

What I want is to bind the events, or at least only take action on those events depending on the current state / context of the application. Is there a good way to handle this?

What I have considered:

1. Using a `Service` that maintains a reference to the state and handles the event binding on a global level to which controllers can subscribe to events based on their context. But I do not know how to subscribe functions to an Angular service in this manor.
2. Unbind and bind events on the `$routeChange` event but feel this could get very messy.

I know this is a conceptual question but I have been stuck on this for some time now and any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I have attempted to make a [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/URI3jXq7ptPkTAiwUuZg?p=preview) to demonstrate this. Each context (an abstract state of the application) has a directive that binds to a `keypress` event. I want event handler on the context in view (i.e. the active state) to be the only one that executes.

I have tried to make a simplified but relevant example. Note:

- Most **but not all** of the contexts/states will have a route associated so I cant just rely on `$stateChange` events
- Many states are modal windows, meaning background elements still visible may also be listening for a key press. I am not sure I can guarantee the DOM order in all cases.
- I have tried using the elements `focus`, but this does not work (think tabbing out and back into the application, problems when those elements involve forms etc.)

Hope this makes it clearer, I am happy to update further.

Comment: Why not stop the events' propagation ?

Comment: This would require the event order be guaranteed such that the correct event handler is fired first. Suppose there were two sections on a page that both bound to a keypress event, is the section in focus always going to be the foremost in the event chain? As far as I know it would be the second one regardless as it would be registered second (in order) but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It depends on the structure of the DOM. Events walk their way from the outer to the inner (e.g. documentElement -> parent-element -> clicked element) during the capture phase and the walk their way back during the bubling phase. If you don't specifically define a listener as executing during the capture phase, it is by default executed during the bubbling phase. So, it is position of the element in the DOM and not the order of registering the listener that determines the order of firing the listeners. Does that make sense ?

Comment: **[This doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)** might help.

Comment: I think I had some concepts mixed up but makes sense yes. Still one event handler would always be called first in the above scenario, this would not always be the desired effect. Obviously I could stop propagation after selecting the correct event handler but I still need to determine that the correct one is executed first and this would depend on current application state not the DOM or event order.

Comment: If you are not registering any event handler to be executed during the capture phase, then it will not fire its callback until the bubbling phase. But if you stop the propagation of the event in a deeper element, then it will never execute the parent's listener. What do you mean by " Still one event handler would always be called first" ? Could you prepare a fiddle demonstrating the problem, so I can see what you mean and provide an appropriate solution ?

Comment: Not sure I follow sorry. I can stop propagation within a deeper element, understood. Then I would do this based on a condition `if (state === foo) { evt.stopPropagation() }`, correct? It is late sorry, I can try make a Plunk in the morning to try demonstrate it better.

Comment: As I said, it is hard to propose a reasonable solution if I don't know the problem exactly (e.g. what is this `state` you refer to ? How does the DOM look like ? etc). I suggest you sleep over this and reviit it in the morning with a plunkr :)

Comment: Thanks @ExpertSystem I have updated the question with a Plunk that I hope explains things better, it is rough but should make it clearer. By `state` I am simply referring to an abstract state of the application (I thought I could name them and use that as a hook to fire the correct event handler that's all sorry for any confusion). I see the app as state based.

Comment: @NinjsPants: Sorry, for the late response (but I am short on freetime lately :)). I took a look at your plunkr and I noticed you bind the events to the document (not to every component). Is that deliberate ? Do you want to receive keypress events on an element even if it does not have the keyboard focus ?

Comment: No problem, I very much appreciate the responses. That is correct, some directives can have events bound to the element itself but in general the events should fire based on the application state not necessarily what has keyboard focus.

Comment: In that case, you can't really use the bubbling of events (since the interested element is not the target of the event). So, what determines the "state" of the application ?

Comment: Basically the context that is currently visible in the browser. Generally there would be a `ui-router` state and URL associated so could use `$state.is(foo)` to check but this is not always the case. The snap-to like functionality in the Plunk (basically untested btw so hope it works somewhat consistently) is to show you can only be in the red or blue states but this is obviously the same route so no separate URL or `ui-router $state`. This is why above I mention possibly of adding a variable to hold the state and/or a `service` to maintain the state and check what events should be fired.

Comment: Yes, I think this should be te way to go. Having a service (or a high-level controller) to maintain state-info and let it decide who get's the event.

Comment: Is there a way to subscribe functions to such a service/controller so a states controller could subscribe to a keypress event something like `stateService.subscribeToKeypress(STATENAME, keycode, controllerFunction)`? The `stateService` would handle binding, maintain a reference to the state and based on those call the subscribed function somehow. maybe map them? If that makes sense, I'm unsure of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy discussion in comments (see above), it boiled down to the requirement of a service that keeps track of the current state and key-presses and accepts "subscriptions" for key-presses when in a specific state.

---

Below is a generic implementation of such a service, with the following attributes:

1. The current-state is set externally (you can implement it is any way you like: ngRoute, uiRouter, $location change events or whatever else might determine the state of your app).
2. It exposes two methods: One for setting the state and one for subscribing to a key-down event for a specific state and keyCode.
3. The subscribe function returns an `unsubscribe` function which can be used for...you guessed it...unsubscribing !
4. This demo implementation assumes that at the time of triggering the key-down event there is no `$digest` cycle in progress. If you have different requirements, you can check before calling `$rootScope.$apply()`.

---

```
app.factory('StateService', function ($document, $rootScope) {
    var currentState = 'init';
    var stateCallbacks = {};

    function fireKeydown(evt) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            ((stateCallbacks[currentState] || {})[evt.keyCode] || []).forEach(
                function (cb) {
                    cb(evt, currentState);
                }
            );
        });
    }

    function setState(newState) {
        currentState = newState;
    }

    function subscribeToKeydown(state, keyCode, callback) {
        if (!state || !keyCode || !callback) {
            return angular.noop;
        }

        stateCallbacks[state] = stateCallbacks[state] || {};
        stateCallbacks[state][keyCode] = stateCallbacks[state][keyCode] || [];
        stateCallbacks[state][keyCode].push(callback);

        function unsubscribe() {
            return ((stateCallbacks[state] || {})[keyCode] || []).some(
                function (cb, idx, arr) {
                    if (cb === callback) {
                        arr.splice(idx, 1);
                        console.log('Unsubscribed from state: ' + state);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        console.log('Subscribed to state: ' + state);        
        return unsubscribe;
    }

    $document.on('keydown', fireKeydown);

    return {
        setState: setState,
        subscribeToKeydown: subscribeToKeydown
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4uaPy/)**.

Comment: Firstly, fantastic answer. An issue has arove though, when switching between `ng-switch` elements with associated controllers the functions subscribe and unsubscribe as expected but after the first switch no `keydown` events are fired anymore. I have tried to replicate it by modifying your demo to no avail. However as no events were getting fired, what does work is changing `$document.on()` to `document.addEventListener()`. Is this acceptable? Does this provide any insight into why event are not being fired after an `ng-switch` when everything else works as expected? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure why this happens. It is strange that you can't replicate it in the demo. Could you check to see if it is a browser-specific issue ? To be honest I've seen similar "oddities" before (when dealing with $document and $window), so I guess using `document.addEventListener()` is fine as well.

Comment: Thanks, have checked the 4 major browsers and same result. If there is no reason not to use `document.addEventListener()` then I will stick with that.